# F#: Why are these brackets necessary (syntax)

Tags: f#

Just for my own peace of mind, I am wondering why, in last line, in my `AssemblyInfo.fs` file, it is neccessary to add a `()` in order for it to compile.  What do you call this syntax?

```
namespace TestComComponentFSharp

open System.Reflection
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<assembly: AssemblyTitle("TestComComponentFSharp")>]
[<assembly: ComVisible(true)>]
[<assembly: Guid("0B684F15-DC37-40C0-A785-EDF1A63BBAF5")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("KeyFile.snk")>]

[<assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>]

()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something to apply those assembly attributes to. That whats the empty () or do() is for. Its called an "Empty Expression" - it returns a unit.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the attributes must apply to something. However, I don't think it "returns" anything, because if I replace it with, for e.g. an integer `0` or a string literal, it gives me the error message "Namespaces cannot contain values. Consider using a module to hold your value declarations."  Am I correct in saying that `()` is both the literal for `void`/`unit`, and  `empty expression` which is empty block syntax?

Comment: No, () or "empty expression" still returns a unit. F# always has to return something. "A "unit" is used to hold the place where a value is required by the language syntax, but when no value is needed or desired." Taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483472.aspx